# Angular 4 Parent Router Outlet from Child Route

Tags: angular

I am trying to achieve a customizable navbar of sorts in my angular application.

Here is my app.component template

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand pageTitle">iMobile</a>
    </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>  

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="authenticated">
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<alert></alert>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and here is my app.routing

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';

// Reports section of the website
import { ReportsComponent } from './reports/index';
import { DashboardComponent } from './reports/dashboard/index';
import { SampleComponent } from './reports/sample/index';

// Corporate section of the website
import { CorporateComponent } from './corporate/index';
import { CorpNavbarComponent } from './corporate/corpNavbar/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'sample', component: SampleComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'corporate', component: CorporateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', component: CorpNavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar'}
        ]
    }


    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'reports' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

What I would like, is to be able to replace the navigation portion of the navbar based on the section of the website. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I'll give it a try.
So, you intend to replace parts of you navbar depending on the page you're currently in?

You can have app component as a hub for all the dynamic parts of your app. Let's suppose you have app component as your basic html structure and three other components that are respectively Navbar1, Navbar2 and Content.

app.component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <router-outlet name="nav"></router-outlet>

    <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then, you would have to specify in your routes where the component has to be loaded:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', outlet: },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, outlet: content },
  { path: 'category1', component: Navbar1, outlet: navbar1 },
```

This link might help you figure it out.

http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

Comment: I have came across that article already. It talks about using named outlets specifically for the child route. What I am trying to accomplish (and it may very well be impossible) is assign a component to the outlet in app.component from the child route. When I do this using the code I posted, i get the error "Cannot find the outlet navbar to load 'CorpNavbarComponent'".

Comment: @Irrelevant_Coder did you find a workaround for this? I found this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10726 Really more so this one https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18271#issuecomment-348071491

Comment: @epelc thanks for following up. I never did find a workaround for this. I just had to shelve the feature I was trying to accomplish until a fix is implemented.